# Automatically add all resources from a directory to the .qrc file

Tags: qt, qml

In order to declare the resources I need in my project, I have to write each of them manually, like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version="1.0">
<qresource>
    <file>resources/copy.png</file>
    <file>resources/cut.png</file>
    <file>resources/new.qml</file>
    <file>resources/open.qml</file>
</qresource>
</RCC>
```

Is there a possibilty to automatically add all the files from a directory to the resouce system, something like below?

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version="1.0">
<qresource>
    <file>resources/*.png</file>
    <file>resources/*.qml</file>
</qresource>
</RCC>
```

Comment: It is still not possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27937654/how-to-specify-wildcards-in-qrc-resource-file-of-qml
It possible to generate qrc file by some script

Comment: @OrestHera, Ah, OK. Anyway, I wonder why I didn't find this question when I searched about this.